# Working with multiple HTML files in Chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have the following question:
I am writing a chrome extension that works with context menu over text selection. one of the things that  I want to do is to create a new tab that is based on one of my html files that I create dynamically using the data I received at the text selection.how do I communicate between my javascript file that is connected  to my background.html and my other html file in order to get to its' DOM and alternate it's contents?

my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My flickr Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png"},
  "background_page":"background.html",
  "permissions": ["tabs",
    "http://api.flickr.com/","contextMenus","http://*/*","https://*/*"  
  ]
}
```

my background.html:

```
<script src="ext.js"></script>

my ext.js main functions:
function searchSelection(info,tab){
    var updated=makeNewString(info.selectionText);
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open(
    "GET",
    "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&text="+updated+"&api_key=a0a60c4e0ed00af8d70800b0987cae70&content_type=1&sort=relevance",
    true);
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhReq.status == 200) {

var photos = xhReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");

var urlOfNew=chrome.extension.getURL('results.html');//this is me getting the link of the other html page that i want to update

    //here I want to manipulate the results.html DOM like adding images depending on the photos and other stuff

                chrome.tabs.create({"selected":true,"url":urlOfNew});
            }
        };
    };
    xhReq.send(null);
}





var context="selection";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "search Flickr", "contexts":[context],"onclick":searchSelection});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Message Passing, http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html, it has detailed examples on how to send messages from Content Script to Extension Page.

Since you are just communicating in the same page (background page), why are you having any trouble? You can just use normal JavaScript to pass variables around.

Comment: I don't want to communicate inside that background.html.

I have an empty blabla.html file.

I use context menu in order to run(using background.html that runs the javascript file- ext.js) some search on my text selection and then the search brings me results and I want to add them as an image to blabla.html file. 
what I want to do and I don't understand how, is I want to have access to the blabla.html DOM in order to add some elements so I can create a new tab that is the blabla.html file that shows the results.

Comment: If you host blabla.html then you can directly get that DOM (of that page) via `chrome.extension.getViews()` and finding the view from it. OR ... You can use Messaging (as I described) where your background page will `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and your blabla.html file will `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`. If you want to create a new file blabla use `chrome.tabs.create` and within its callback, you can pass data.

Comment: this blabla.html has no hosting it's just an empty html file that is in the folder of the extension. when I do get views I don't receive this page. only if I first create a new tab, and it's not what I want. I want to first edit this html page and then create a new tab with it.
and I'l check out the messaging I haven't tried it yet.
Thanks
Mary

Comment: Open the new tab with that html page, and in the callback of `chrome.tabs.create` you can inject that page with stuff that you want. Or with JavaScript, on windows load event, with that html page it will populate with what you need. Messaging is whats needed.

Comment: ok. but in order to use messaging I need to define content scripts at my manifest.json file. how do I do that using my blabla.html?

Comment: No problem :) You can use messaging for anything (Extension <-> Extension) or (Extension <-> Content-Scripts). If your in Extension <-> Extension, you can get a reference to the background page DOM via `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` or via `chrome.extension.getViews()` Great to see you got it figured out!